# How do I add Aosp-Node-Prebuilts to the Orange Pi 4 LTS Android 8.1 build?

Tags: android, embedded, android-source, orange-pi

Following the instructions in the [Aosp-Node-Prebuilts](https://github.com/fdgonthier/Aosp-Node-Prebuilts) [README](https://github.com/fdgonthier/Aosp-Node-Prebuilts/blob/master/README.md), I cloned the repository in the external directory of the [Orange Pi 4 LTS RK3399-Android8.1](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-2ZsmvpGrdBQcbMrJVvkzp-Vrops2M4Q) tree (which I have successfully built), and successfully ran `make arm64`. But because I build using the `build.sh` included in the Orange Pi 4 LTS Android sources, my shell is not "initialised with the buildenv and lunch combo".

The README states:

> If you want the Android.mk to be executed automatically, add it as a
> dependency of another project.

How do I add Aosp-Node-Prebuilts as a dependency of another project?

I tried adding "Aosp-Node-Prebuilts" to `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` in `build/make/target/product/base.mk`, but that didn't work.

I tried searching for how other packages in the external directory with `Android.mk` files are added as a dependency, but didn't find anything. (I searched for `strace` and `tcpdump`--both of which I confirmed are in `/system/xbin` on the target.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the equivalent of "adding Aosp-Node-Prebuilts as a dependency of another project" by adding `node` to `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` in `build/make/target/product/base.mk`:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    node \
    20-dns.conf \
...
```

I believe the package name is "node" because `LOCAL_MODULE` is set to `node` in the Aosp-Node-Prebuilts [Android.mk](https://github.com/fdgonthier/Aosp-Node-Prebuilts/blob/master/Android.mk) file. I confirmed this worked by adding this to `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD := echo "Aosp-Node-Prebuilts LOCAL_SRC_FILES: $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)"
```

...and I confirmed this was echoed when I ran the build:

```
Aosp-Node-Prebuilts LOCAL_SRC_FILES: target/node
```

I also confirmed that `target/node` in the `external/Aosp-Node-Prebuilts` directory was copied to `out/target/product/rk3399/system/bin`. And I mounted the `system.img` on Linux and confirmed it is in `/system/bin`.